# Error when trying to create New Scaffolded Item - .NET MVC Entity Framework Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, visual-studio-2017, asp.net-mvc-scaffolding

Following [this Virtual Academy](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ok3kajIFHow&t=3034s), and about 37:00 in they go to create a new scaffolded item from the Album model and context they created. Mine fails. I've googled, and tried creating 3 separate projects, targeting .net core 2.0, 1.1, and 1.0 respectively. Visual Studio 2017.

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WebApplication4.Models
{
    public class Album
    {
        public int AlbumId { get; set; }
        public String Title { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
    }

    public class MusicContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Album> Albums { get; set; }
    }
}
```

[image]

[image]

Does anyone know a fix? Point me in the right direction? Did I miss a step? There's only 2 :D

-----Update------

Looking around it seems 'Codegeneration.Tools' is not installed. Trying to install it threw the error

`Package 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Tools 2.0.1' has a package type 'DotnetCliTool' that is not supported by project 'WebApplication4'`

-----Update 201712111428------

This *did* work with VS 2015 and EntityFramework 6.1.2. Maybe the problem is with VS 2017.